# Decreasing a variable whilst a screen is touched

Tags: sprite-kit

I want to decrease a score whilst the screen is touched with Swift and I am unsure which way is the best to achieve this.

Placing:

```
score -= 1
```

in touches began obviously decreases it when the screen is touched, but I need it to do it the whole time the screen is touched.

I tried to create an SKAction to run the code above forever in touchesBegan and then remove the action in touchesEnded. This just caused the app to freeze.

I know it should be easy, but any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Set a flag  in `touchesBegan` to indicate that the screen has been touched:

`screentouched = true`

and then reset the flag in `touchesEnded` to show that the screen is no longer being touched:

`screenTouched = false`

In `update`, if `screenTouched` is `true`, decrease your score

`if screenTouched {
   score -= 1
}`

Although this will result in the score being decremented up to 60 times a second, so you’ll probably want to restrict by time. To do this, have 2 properties of type `TimeInterval` that track how long it has been since the score was last decremented, and how often the score should be decremented:

```
  var timeOfLastScoreDecrement: CFTimeInterval = 0.0
  var timePerScoreDecrement: CFTimeInterval = 1.0
```

For this example, we'll decrement the score every second and set the time since the last decrement to 0, as it hasn't happened yet.

In `update:` call a function that checks to see if the time interval has passed. If it has, then decrement the score and reset to time since the last decrement and if it hasn’t, don’t:

```
override func update(_ currentTime: TimeInterval) {
   if screenIsTouched {decrementScoreForTime(currentTime)}
   // Rest of update code
   }

func decrementScoreForTime(_ currentTime: CFTimeInterval) {
   if (currentTime - timeOfLastScoreDecrement < timePerScoreDecrement) {return}
   // Time per score decrement has passed...
   score -= 1
   timeOfLastScoreDecrement = currentTime
   }
```

Comment: Your solution is great and easy to follow. Thank you. I guess another way would be to make the score not an integer and decrease by a 1/60th each update? Either way, thanks for your time and sharing your knowledge.

Comment: The trouble is that you can’t guarantee `update` being called 60 times a second. I know this way works but you could also do something with an SKAction which you create when the screen is touched and you delete when the touch ends.

Comment: Ok. Yes. I see. I will stick with your original way. Thank you.

Comment: It's also very easy (and the code is obvious) to implement bonuses & penalties  that change the rate at which the score change and by how much, just by updating those `CFTimeInterval` properties.